# Adding pdf file with rest call GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl add() to sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, file-upload, folder, pdf

I have read some articles about adding a file to SharePoint where the body contains text when using a REST POST call with GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl body add().

Can anybody help me to add a pdf file this way. See below as an example I found while googling ?

What is the field to be used?

```
url: http://site url/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/Folder Name')/Files/add(url='a.txt',overwrite=true)
method: POST
body: "Contents of file"
Headers: 
Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken
X-RequestDigest: form digest value
content-length:length of post body
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can refer below code to create a file in SharePoint using rest.

```
function createDocument() {
var docTitle = "testFile.pdf";
var docContent = "Test content";

var fullUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl+ "/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Shared Documents')/Files/add(url='" + docTitle +"',overwrite=true)";

$.ajax({
url: fullUrl,
type: "POST",
data: docContent,
headers: {
"accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
"content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
"X-RequestDigest":$("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
},
success: function(){alert('pass')},
error: function(){alert('fail')}
});
}
```

Add you can call createDocument() function when you need to create a file.
[Reference](https://www.enjoysharepoint.com/create-and-delete-file-using-rest-api-in-sharepoint/)